# Not able get inflate view into list view using custom adapter

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to get the below view which is in a list

[image]

Following is the code I used

```
package com.solodroid.ecommerce;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Html;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.rakyow.srptjobportal.R;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
* Created by user on 3/29/2016.
*/
public class ActivityJobByCategory extends Activity {
ArrayList<JobsByCategory> listOfJobs = new ArrayList<JobsByCategory>();
ListView listView;
Long categoryId;
ProgressBar prgLoading;
TextView txtAlert;
String jobName, jobLocation, fromDate, toDate, fromPackage, toPackage, jobType, jobguid;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.job_list);
    ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
    bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.header)));
    bar.setTitle("Jobs Found");
    bar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    bar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    //     prgLoading = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.prgLoading);
    //    txtAlert = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtAlert);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listMenu);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        categoryId = extras.getLong("category_id");
    }

    new task().execute();

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            // app icon in action bar clicked; go home
            this.finish();
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.open_main, R.anim.close_next);
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

class task extends AsyncTask<String, String, Void> {
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(ActivityJobByCategory.this);
    InputStream is = null;
    String result = "";

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.show();
        progressDialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
            public void onCancel(DialogInterface arg0) {
                task.this.cancel(true);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

        String url_select = "http://jobportal.rakyow.com/website/joblist/lists?catid=" + categoryId;
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url_select);
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> param = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        try {
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(param));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            Log.d("Amit", "executed httppost");
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            Log.d("Amit", "Got response");
            // read content
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
            Log.d("Amit", "Got content");
        } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
        }
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(is));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = "";
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                Log.d("Amit", "line = " + line);
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();
            Log.d("Amit", "Result = " + result);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void v) {

        try {
            JSONObject object = new JSONObject(result);
            Log.d("Amit", "created jsonobject");
            JSONArray userDetailsArray = object.getJSONArray("data");
            Log.d("Amit", "Got userDetails");
            ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < userDetailsArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject obj = userDetailsArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    Log.d("Amit", "inside " + i);
                    jobName = obj.getString("job_title");
                    jobLocation = obj.getString("location");
                    fromDate = obj.getString("from_date");
                    toDate = obj.getString("to_date");
                    fromPackage = obj.getString("from_package");
                    toPackage = obj.getString("package");
                    jobType = obj.getString("job_type");
                    jobguid = obj.getString("guid");

                    JobsByCategory job = new JobsByCategory(jobName, jobLocation, fromDate, toDate, fromPackage, toPackage, jobType, jobguid);

                    listOfJobs.add(job);

                }

                this.progressDialog.dismiss();
                // get an output on the screen

                //set adapter for listview


                JobsAdapter adapter = new JobsAdapter(ActivityJobByCategory.this, listOfJobs);
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                Log.d("Amit", "adapter set");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }
    }


}

public class JobsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<JobsByCategory> {
    // View lookup cache

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView job_name, job_location, date, packages, job_type;

    }/*@Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listOfOrders.size();
    }*/

    public JobsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<JobsByCategory> orders) {

        super(context, R.layout.menu_list_item, orders);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Get the data item for this position
        final JobsByCategory jobs = getItem(position);
        Log.d("Amit2", "reached adapter getView");
        //  Log.d("Akhilesh", loads.loadType);
        // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
        ViewHolder viewHolder; // view lookup cache stored in tag
        if (convertView == null) {
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_list_item, parent, false);
            viewHolder.job_name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.jobName);
            viewHolder.job_location = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.jobLocation);
            viewHolder.date = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dates);
            viewHolder.packages = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.salary);
            viewHolder.job_type = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.jobType);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            Log.d("Amit", "set adapter view");
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            Log.d("Amit", " not set adapter view");
        }
        // Populate the data into the template view using the data object
        viewHolder.job_name.setText(jobs.jobName);
        viewHolder.job_location.setText(jobs.location);
        viewHolder.date.setText(jobs.fromDate + "-" + jobs.toDate);
        viewHolder.packages.setText(jobs.fromPackage + "-" + jobs.toPackage);
        viewHolder.job_type.setText(jobs.jobType);
        Log.d("Amit", "set all values");
        return convertView;
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onBackPressed();
    finish();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.open_main, R.anim.close_next);
}

}
```

JobsByCategory.class is

```
package com.solodroid.ecommerce;

public class JobsByCategory {
String jobName;
String location;
String fromDate;
String toDate;
String fromPackage;
String toPackage;
String jobType;
String jobGuid;

// Constructor to convert JSON object into a Java class instance
public JobsByCategory(String jN, String lO, String fD, String tD, String fP , String tP , String jT , String gD) {

    this.jobName = jN;
    this.location =lO;
    this.fromDate = fD;
    this.toDate = tD;
    this.fromPackage =fP;
    this.toPackage =tP;
    this.jobType =jT;
    this.jobGuid =gD;


}

public String getJobName() {
    return jobName;
}
public String getLocation() {
    return location;
}
public String getFromDate() {
    return fromDate;
}
public  String getToDate(){
    return toDate;
}
public String getFromPackage() {
    return fromPackage;
}
public String getToPackage() {
    return toPackage;
}
public String getJobType() {
    return jobType;
} public String getJobGuid() {
    return jobGuid;
}
```

}

I am not not able to get the view.But no errors are coming.Can any one help me in solving this issue?

Xml files

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:background="#e7e7e7" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lytSearch"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:background="@color/header"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:visibility="visible" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edtKeyword"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/search_form"
            android:hint="@string/search"
            android:padding="7dp"
            android:textColor="@color/hint"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:singleLine="true" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnSearch"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:background="@color/header"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_search" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:id="@+id/listMenu"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lytSearch"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:padding="5dp" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/prgLoading"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/txtAlert"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/not_found"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

   </RelativeLayout>
```

Custom View

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/button_top_style_1"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="5dp" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Accountant"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/jobName"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold|italic"
    android:background="#7153ff"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:background="#69c9ff">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/jobLocation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/dates"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/placeholder"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:padding="10sp"
        android:text="aaa"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="false" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dates"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/calendar"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="bbb" />

   </RelativeLayout>
   <RelativeLayout

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:background="#69c9ff">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/salary"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/jobType"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/rupee"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:padding="10sp"
        android:text="4 lakhs"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/jobType"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Full Time"
        android:autoText="true"
        android:background="#ff8058"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: In JobsAdapter under the getView you need to return view.

Comment: I have added..but still no luck

Comment: please post error what you have??

Comment: I am not getting any error..But when I put log I noticed that its not entering into getview() method

Comment: uncomment the getCount() method and return the size of your order list and check the getItem method once..

Comment: uncmment the getCount method. it is provided size of item to array adapter.

Comment: @all please upvote others answers and comments , pls don copy it. Its against rule of stack overflow

Comment: I have uncommented getCount method..whats next?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add below line at the bottom of `getView()` method and check if you are getting your view.

```
return convertView;
```

Replace your classes with below classes its working now:

(Note:I have removed images from all layouts to make this run as I hadn't any images of yours)

1) ActivityJobByCategory.java

```
package com.example.c109.temp;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ActivityJobByCategory extends AppCompatActivity {
    ArrayList<JobsByCategory> listOfJobs = new ArrayList<JobsByCategory>();
    ListView listView;
    Long categoryId;
    ProgressBar prgLoading;
    TextView txtAlert;
    String jobName, jobLocation, fromDate, toDate, fromPackage, toPackage, jobType, jobguid;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.job_list);
        android.support.v7.app.ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();
        // bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.header)));
        bar.setTitle("Jobs Found");
        bar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        bar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        //     prgLoading = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.prgLoading);
        //    txtAlert = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtAlert);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listMenu);
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            categoryId = extras.getLong("category_id");
        }

        new task().execute();


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                // app icon in action bar clicked; go home
                this.finish();
                // overridePendingTransition(R.anim.class, R.anim.close_next);
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onBackPressed();
        finish();
        //overridePendingTransition(R.anim.open_main, R.anim.close_next);
    }


    public class JobsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        // View lookup cache
        ArrayList<JobsByCategory> orders = new ArrayList<>();
        Context mContext;

        private class ViewHolder {
            TextView job_name, job_location, date, packages, job_type;

        }


        /*@Override
        public int getCount() {
            return orders.size();
        }*/

        public JobsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<JobsByCategory> orders) {

            mContext = context;
            this.orders = orders;

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return orders.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return orders.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // Get the data item for this position
            final JobsByCategory jobs = (JobsByCategory) getItem(position);
            Log.d("Amit2", "reached adapter getView");
            //  Log.d("Akhilesh", loads.loadType);
            // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
            ViewHolder viewHolder; // view lookup cache stored in tag
            if (convertView == null) {
                viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_list_item, parent, false);
                viewHolder.job_name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.jobName);
                viewHolder.job_location = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.jobLocation);
                viewHolder.date = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dates);
                viewHolder.packages = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.salary);
                viewHolder.job_type = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.jobType);
                convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
                Log.d("Amit", "set adapter view");
            } else {
                viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                Log.d("Amit", " not set adapter view");
            }
            // Populate the data into the template view using the data object
            viewHolder.job_name.setText(jobs.jobName);
            viewHolder.job_location.setText(jobs.location);
            viewHolder.date.setText(jobs.fromDate + "-" + jobs.toDate);
            viewHolder.packages.setText(jobs.fromPackage + "-" + jobs.toPackage);
            viewHolder.job_type.setText(jobs.jobType);
            Log.d("Amit", "set all values");
            return convertView;
        }
    }

    class task extends AsyncTask<String, String, Void> {
        private ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(ActivityJobByCategory.this);
        InputStream is = null;
        String result = "";

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            progressDialog.show();
           /* progressDialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                public void onCancel(DialogInterface arg0) {
                    task.this.cancel(true);
                }
            });*/
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

            String url_select = "http://jobportal.rakyow.com/website/joblist/lists?catid=" + categoryId;
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url_select);
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> param = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            try {
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(param));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                Log.d("Amit", "executed httppost");
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                Log.d("Amit", "Got response");
                // read content
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
                Log.d("Amit", "Got content");
            } catch (Exception e) {

                Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
            }
            try {
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(is));
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = "";
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    Log.d("Amit", "line = " + line);
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                is.close();
                result = sb.toString();
                Log.d("Amit", "Result = " + result);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
            }

            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void v) {

            try {
                this.progressDialog.dismiss();
                JSONObject object = new JSONObject(result);
                Log.d("Amit", "created jsonobject");
                JSONArray userDetailsArray = object.getJSONArray("data");
                Log.d("Amit", "Got userDetails");
                ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
                try {
                    for (int i = 0; i < userDetailsArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject obj = userDetailsArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        Log.d("Amit", "inside " + i);
                        jobName = obj.getString("job_title");
                        jobLocation = obj.getString("location");
                        fromDate = obj.getString("from_date");
                        toDate = obj.getString("to_date");
                        fromPackage = obj.getString("from_package");
                        toPackage = obj.getString("package");
                        jobType = obj.getString("job_type");
                        jobguid = obj.getString("guid");

                        JobsByCategory job = new JobsByCategory(jobName, jobLocation, fromDate, toDate, fromPackage, toPackage, jobType, jobguid);

                        listOfJobs.add(job);

                    }


                    // get an output on the screen

                    //set adapter for listview


                    JobsAdapter adapter = new JobsAdapter(ActivityJobByCategory.this, listOfJobs);
                    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    Log.d("Amit", "adapter set");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
            }
        }


    }

}
```

2) job_list.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#e7e7e7" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lytSearch"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="45dp"

    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:visibility="visible" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtKeyword"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"

        android:padding="7dp"

        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:singleLine="true" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnSearch"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3"
         />

</LinearLayout>

<ListView
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:id="@+id/listMenu"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/lytSearch"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:padding="5dp" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/prgLoading"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtAlert"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:visibility="gone"/>
```

3) menu_list_item.xml

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="5dp" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Accountant"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/jobName"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold|italic"
    android:background="#7153ff"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:background="#69c9ff">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/jobLocation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/dates"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:padding="10sp"
        android:text="aaa"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="false"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dates"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="bbb" />

</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:background="#69c9ff">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/salary"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/jobType"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:padding="10sp"
        android:text="4 lakhs"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/jobType"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Full Time"
        android:autoText="true"
        android:background="#ff8058"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I have added..but still no luck

Comment: ok put your xml files I will check in studio adding your files.

Comment: I have put xml files also

Comment: @AmitNair, instead of my answer, change your acceptance to this answer.

Answer (score 1):

why `getCount` is commented how your adapter suppose to know number of items

you call `final JobsByCategory jobs = getItem(position)`;

but with no count

Comment: I have uncommentd that ..but now also I am not able to get the view

Comment: are you sure that the arraylist is not empty?

Comment: No its not empty...Because I am printing the json object which is not empty

Answer (score 1):

Your view is complex to use ArrayAdapter, try to use BaseAdapter instead.

1_ Change `extends ArrayAdapter<JobsByCategory>` to `extends BaseAdapter`

2_ Change your code like below:

```
    ArrayList<JobsByCategory> mOrderList;
    Context mContext;
    public JobsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<JobsByCategory> orders) {
          mContext = context;
          mOrderList = orders;
    }
    @Override
    public JobsByCategory getItem(int position) {
        return mOrderList.get(position)
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
         return position;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mOrderList.size();
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ...
     if (convertView == null) {
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);

    ...
    }
```

3_ Your xml has problem:

```
<ListView
        android:visibility="gone"
```

Change `gone` to `visible` or remove this line

And try to test it again!

Comment: final JobsByCategory jobs = getItem(position);
Error in this line of incompatible types after changing to BaseAdapter

Comment: See my changes again

Comment: Ok lemme check..I will let you know after that

Comment: I suggest move your `Adapter` class alone or make it static class, not a non-static inner class. It may cause your app memory leaks problem.

Comment: no progress. :( I think still its not entering into the getView method because the log inside getView method is not getting printed.Why so?

Comment: Did the log `Log.d("Amit", "adapter set");` show? if it showed, try add the line `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` after this log.

Comment: Yes thats the last log  working for me and I have added adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); What next? I am a beginner in android..please pardon if I ask

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115089/discussion-between-amit-nair-and-john-steve).

Comment: Let me check and run